# Next.jsでTwitter共有用画像が設定できない

Tags: reactjs, next.js

AppRouterのNext.jsでの質問です

Twitterの共有用画像を設定する際に、[この公式ドキュメント](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/opengraph-image#twitter-imagealttxt)にかいてあるような手法をとって行っているのですが、なぜか上手くいきません

上記のドキュメントの1つ目の方法である、「appディレクトリ直下にtwitter-image.pngを置く」という方法を選択してビルド&デプロイしたのですが、開発者ツールからデプロイ済みのサイトの開発者ツールを見るとメタタグに
`<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://localhost:3000/twitter-image.png?eb9d9c66353bcc90">`
という風に出ているのです

これはローカルだけでの話ではなくて、しっかりデプロイしてある本番環境でも画像のパスが`http://localhost:3000/twitter-image.png?eb9d9c66353bcc90`となります

調べても関連する情報が一切出てこず、対処法が分かりません
Headで行う方法でも両立ができないようだったので、完全に詰まってしまいました

本番環境でも画像のパスがlocalhostのものになってしまう理由と、対処法を教えてください